# An old half remembered scene from an unknown movie/TV show where two astronauts are fighting inside their ship

Tags: story-identification, androids, astronauts

One subdues the other and in so doing discovers that his companion is, and has been, a robot the whole time. Gasp! Moments later he tries to pull a bulkhead closed in the damaged ship. He pulls so hard that he tears his arm open, and discovers that he too is a robot.

Right, good points.
I saw it on late night television in Australia sometime in the late 80's.
I think it was in color. I think both actor's were white and male, the survivor was a younger male. They were both clean cut and responsible in appearance and manner.

It may be that my memory is influenced by other films like Kubric's 2001, but I think that the younger male, even though disoriented by his discoveries, persists in carrying out his mission.

I can't remember what kind injury he inflicted on his companion, but somehow, it reveals the interior is mechanical/electrical, rods and wires. This set's up the reveal for when he tears his own arm.

Both actors otherwise looked completely human, with no visual give-aways that both are androids. I can't recall the conflict that instigates the fight.

I don't think this was a 50's or 60's era production. I don't recall any Gernsbackian scifi influences in the design or plot.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: [The Human Duplicators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2j9jWFjE_I) has much the same themes.

Comment: @valorum I don't believe the film had any fantastical/early-scifi elements to it. I believe it was somewhat proceedural, which is why the twists are so memorable. In design there were no outlandish costumes, or aliens (I think).

Answer (score 7):

It might be [Android (1982)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(film))

> In 2036, an android named Max 404, and his creator, Doctor Daniel, reside aboard a remote space station. Although Max is a machine, he has a growing interest in all things human, especially sex. After Daniel starts to notice Max's character is changing, Max eavesdrops on the doctor's report that Max's growing insubordinate behavior could lead to a revolt similar to an incident back on Earth known as the "Munich Rebellion", after which androids were outlawed. However, Daniel is illegally working on another android, Cassandra One, intended to be a superior machine and which has the form of a human female.

> Max returns to the lab, where Daniel has made sexual advances towards a now-completed Cassandra, who is resisting. Daniel asks Max to hold Cassandra, but when Max refuses to obey, Daniel begins to struggle with the two androids and eventually they rip off Daniel's head, revealing that Daniel is also an android.

What matches:

- right date, (1982)
- Two men on a space station
- One is young, the other is older
- Both are androids
- They both look exactly human
- Surprise twist, The older one is revealed as an android during a fight

What doesn't match:

- Max and Cassandra are shown right from the start to be android. No surprise.
- I don't recall anything about Max damaging his arm. (mind you, it has been 30+ years since I saw it)

Here's the trailer, does it look familiar?

Comment: might want to add spoiler tags (`>!`) for the "Max returns" part...

Comment: Why? It doesn't hide anything. The OP asks about a film where characters turn out to be androids.Any film mentioned in this thread will have that twist. People will know the twist in the film as soon as the title is mentioned. A spoiler box won't change that.